# Derby Parse Image Hex in Smaller Chunks for Blob Column

Tags: java, derby

I have a Blob column to stores images. I am using Java to dump the database into an SQL script to use for testing purposes. I have everything but images coming out.

I setup the output of the Blob to `byte[]` using `blobValue.getBytes(1L, blobValue.length())` then convert to a hex string using this SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9855338). I then used what was recommended from [DERBY-2198](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DERBY-2198?focusedCommentId=12460117&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-12460117) comment to cast hex to blob in the SQL script:

```
CAST(X'<HEX STRING>' AS BLOB)
```

I am assuming this is going to work, but if not, then I welcome a better solution.

As it stands, I was unable to insert into the database with the SQL script because I am getting an error that states the string constant is too long.

```
java.sql.SQLException: A string constant starting with 'X'<First ~60 Chars>&' is too long.
```

and if I run through NetBeans

```
[Exception, Error Code 0, SQLState 54002] A string constant starting with ... is too long.
```

I have tried breaking the string down into smaller chunks of about 58 hex long and using Derby [concatenation](https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.13/ref/rrefsqlj40899.html) by use of `||` between the strings.

This gets me a statement that contains

```
CAST (X'<58 HEX Length>' || '<Another 58 HEX Length>' || ... AS BLOB)
```

Doing so gets me another error.

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: No authorized routine named '||' of type 'FUNCTION' 
    having compatible arguments was found.
```

I tried looking for other solutions, but I could not find anything to get around this issue.

Is there anything that I can do? Is something missing?

Comment: It's a little hard to tell, but since you said "dump the database ... to use ... for testing", are you perhaps looking for http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.15/ref/rrefexportproctablelobs.html

Comment: @BryanPendleton I do not think so. Though I cannot be sure without an example of an output file. But the way that we get the output is by querying the data into a Java object and putting it into an SQL script file of insert commands.

Comment: Did you find a solution for the "A string constant starting with ... is too long" error message?